# Real-time FFT Pitch shifting in c#

Tags: fft, pitch, c#

I'm using Math.net and Bass.Net to write FX effects for guitars. I'm currently stuck on the the pitch shifter. I have to implement a custom DSP callback function which provides the guitar PCM data and the length in bytes (the sample rate is 44100 Hz). I currently use the FFT implementation of Math.Net, but I don't know what to do with the complex output. My code is the following:

```
        //buffer (IntPtr) contains the PCM data in 32-bit floating point samples
        //length (int) is the number of bytes to process

        Complex[] cOutput = new Complex[length/4]; //allocate the buffer to store the complex numbers 
        float* data = (float*)buffer;
        for (int i = 0; i < (length / 4); i++)
        {
            cOutput[i] = new Complex((double)data[i], 0.0); //fill the Complex array
        }

        Fourier.Forward(cOutput); //apply the FFT to the filled Complex array and overwrite its data
```

So I'm now have an array of Complex, but I don't know what part of this array I have to modify to change the pitch. So what comes next in the pitch shifting algorithm?

Thanks for your help

Comment: Have you looked up the different methods of time-pitch modification and chosen one?

Comment: No, I haven't found any. Where can I find those?

Comment: Maybe start with https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pitch

Comment: I looked there, but I couldn't find anything that could help me with my problem.

Comment: You will have to do a lot more than "look".  Try studying: time pitch modification, PSOLA, phase vocoder, etc.  Follow the references.